# Download Manager for downloading a file in typo3 version 7.6.20

Tags: typo3, download-manager

I have typo3 version 7.6.20 with php 7.3.26 and would provide a file for downloading only for registrated users. What will be the best way.
This ext [Download Manager](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/reint_downloadmanager) tells me, that my PHP version is to high. And that ext [secure download](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/fr_pwsdownload) causes my system to crash. (I get this error: [error and reseting my typo3 system](https://www.mail-archive.com/typo3-english@lists.typo3.org/msg31239.html))
What is compatible or what could I do?
Thanks
Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - since both, TYPO3 and PHP are quite outdated, IMHO the thing you should do in the first place is: Upgrade that system immediately to CMS 10 at least, maybe CMS 9 with ELTS support, and PHP 7.4.

Download Manager is available up to CMS 11, so your actual problem should be fixed by those upgrades too.